# MS Access - #Name? error in control source for a text box with VBA and expression

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on a report that uses a few text fields from a table for various labels on the report, and one field is for populating an image. This field, `photoFileName`, is the string of the image file, e.g. `IMG_10.JPG`. I am using VBA to save the reports in separate files based on a group; the report is grouped by a `tankID` field in the table, and I want each group to save to a separate PDF. This part is working, as in each PDF has the right filename and layout and populated text fields, but with this VBA, the images are no longer showing in any of the saved PDFs.

The grouping is working properly, and the labels using non-`photoFileName` fields in the report are populating correctly. Only the image that uses the expression `=[CurrentProject].[Path] & "\ResizedPhotos\" & [photoFileName]` for its control source is not working, and results in no image showing. I tried to debug using a text box with the same expression above, and it shows a `#Name?` value only. If I just put `photoFileName` in the control source, the right value shows up. It is only when put in an expression that it doesn't work.

Here is the VBA for reference:

```
Sub macro1()

    Set tankIDs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT tankID FROM [photoLog]")

    With tankIDs
        Do Until .EOF
            DoCmd.OpenReport "Photo Appendix", _
                acViewPreview, _
                WhereCondition:="tankID = " & Chr(34) & !tankID & Chr(34), _
                WindowMode:=acHidden

            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, _
                "Photo Appendix", _
                acFormatPDF, _
                "E:\Photo log\test\" & !tankID & ".pdf"

            DoCmd.Close acReport, "Photo Appendix", acSaveNo

            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The control and the field (table/query) are named`? That works as control-source is same as fieldname. But when you add an expression,you create a circular reference as now both have different values, but same name. Change controlname to e.g`ctlphotoFileName`. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/255812/ms-access-concat-a-string-with-control-source

Comment: @ComputerVersteher  the image control name and the field name are unfortunately already different. I think the problem must be related to the VBA because that's the only difference that caused the image to not show up.

Comment: Sorry the error was #type for that. DB complies and is repaired. Add a textbox for the first part of the path too`=[CurrentProject].[Path] & "\ResizedPhotos\"`

Comment: i've tried that already too, it works fine. The only combinations of parts of the control source that cause the `#Name?` error are the ones involving the `[photoFileName]` with another part

Comment: Now combine the textbox values to the full path in picture control source`= textBox1.value & Textbox2.Value`. Still working? If yes and you want  to find the error cause, post your report as textfile (export with`Application.SaveAsText acReport, "reportname" , "Path\to\savred\File"`

Comment: I don't get #Name? error. Code works for me. What is image file type? A png image shows but jpeg will not.

Comment: Why does question topic reference a textbox, isn't this expression in an Image control?

Comment: @June7 a textbox was used to debug the missing images  Why should jpeg's not show in image control?

Comment: I don't know why jpeg is failing, but it does. Also, jpg works.

Comment: @June7 .jpeg works for me, but I always use .jpg as extentsion.

Comment: @June7 did you try with the VBA? That's the only time it doesn't work for me

Comment: Yes, I tested VBA with a grouped report. I have known report not to recognize a field used in an expression if a control was not bound to that field. However, I did not experience that in this test. Try binding textbox to field and see if expression resolves. Or another approach is to put `CurrentProject.Path & "\ResizedPhotos\" & [photoFileName]` expression in report RecordSource query. Bind Image control to that constructed field.

Comment: @June7 I tried binding a textbox to the field and using it in the path construction control, but that didn't work. Not sure what you mean by the "report RecordSource query" part; that is currently set to be the overall table used for the report so i don't think that needs to be changed? (I'm pretty new to Access so please excuse my rookie-ness)

Comment: A form or report RecordSource can be a table or a query object or an SQL statement. So construct a field with expression in query and use that query object or SQL statement in RecordSource: `SELECT *, CurrentProject.Path & "\ResizedPhotos\" & [photoFileName] AS Img FROM photolog;`. `#Name?` error means Access cannot find the referenced name. If this query does not work then we don't have enough info to provide solution.